# manipulate the button backbutton ApacheCordova

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

Must handle the back button , so you block if the page is a login. Already I tried many ways, but none worked. I got closer to these attempts:

I try "document.referrer" : but returns empty.
Try  $routeChangeStart but the method is called backButtonHandler first, then check this method is ignored.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var pageHistoryCount = 0;
    var goingBack = false;

    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);



    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events

        document.addEventListener('pause', onPause.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('resume', onResume.bind(this), false);
        document.addEventListener('backbutton',backButtonHandler.bind(this), false);    
        // TODO: Cordova has been loaded. Perform any initialization that requires Cordova here.
    };

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };

    function exitApp() {
        navigator.app.exitApp();
    };


    function backButtonHandler(e) {
        window.history.back();
         // i need this logic
        //if(previus=="login"){
        //       }else{window.history.back(); }
    };


})();
```

Comment: Are you using a framework like AngularJS  with the router plugin?  Something else?  See http://www.jonahnisenson.com/angular-js-ui-router-redirect-after-login-to-requested-url/

Comment: I'm not using any plugins , but it does not work for me, the login page is called the same way , I can not do verification on the login page .

Comment: What platform are you building on that is causing problems?  Android?  iOS?  Device?  Simulator / emulator?

Comment: are you storing a value on previus?

Comment: don't try to mess with the back button. instead, reroute users if they are not authenticated and attempt to hit any route that is not the login page. that way, even if they hit the back button while on the login screen, it will still just reroute them back to the login screen.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Douglas Timms. It's better practice to check if users have been authenticated when they try to access any post-login pages, and if not, to redirect them back to the login page. In Javascript, you can track when the user is trying to go down a new path with the pageload or deviceready event.